# Get all organizations via REST API for Azure DevOps

Tags: rest, azure-devops

Is it possible to get a list of all the organizations a user is allocated to, via the Azure DevOps REST API's?

From what I can see, the REST API's are organization specific.

Comment: Even using the [Graph to list memberships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list) requires an organization, so I'm guessing it's not supported.

Comment: Your [Azure DevOps profile page](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me) _does_ show **Organizations in Other Enterprises**. I quickly scanned the calls the frontend makes, but couldn't recognize one as returning this information. Might be an internal call.

Comment: @rickvdbosch also thought i could get a reference in fiddler, but no luck. graph wasn't much help either, so i decided to ask the experts on here :). i'll contact our Microsoft guys here in SA and find out if they know about such a call. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all organizations in Azure DevOps using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762368/get-all-organizations-in-azure-devops-using-rest-api)

Answer (score 7):

You can get the list of organization using Azure DevOps REST APIs

First get the profile of logged in user
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
if you are using OAuth authentication, use

API
`GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.0`

Response
`{ "displayName": "User Name", "publicAlias": "67861230-823749-915c-887ed4ccf1f1", "emailAddress": "email@outlook.com", "coreRevision": 7678234, "timeStamp": "2018-12-15T02:06:10.2750402+00:00", "id": "67861230-823749-915c-887ed4ccf1f1", "revision": 7678234 }`

Use `publicAlias` to get the list of organization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

API `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?memberId={publicAlias}&api-version=6.0`

Comment: Same for me, this is the correct solution