# How to get the list of Azure DevOps organizations in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I'm part of more than one organization in Azure DevOps. It's easy to navigate between organizations in Web interface. But I'm looking to get the list of my organization in C#.

I can't find anything related in these links and in Google:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/devops/1485/using-rest-api-azure-devops

Comment: Why do you ask? You also asked on another question of mine. And you deleted your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [accounts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: Any word on how to get the `properties` to expand, or what values to expect in that property? The documentation is pretty scant.

Comment: Where should I get my `memberId` from?

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli Member ID is optional.

Comment: No, it's not optional. This is the error I get: `{
$id: "1",
innerException: null,
message: "Necessary parameters ownerId or memberId were not provided in the request.",
typeName: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Account.AccountException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
typeKey: "AccountException",
errorCode: 0,
eventId: 4236
}`

Comment: @JoshGust i was wondering the same, years later and still the documentation on it is really bad. Was trying to implement the call with .NET Client libraries but cant find the accounts class anywhere.
Also for getting your memberId go to the profile operation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299987/5294174

Answer (score 1):

Create PAT:

[image]

Get member ID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

[image]

Copy Id of a user from result and call REST API to get organizations:

[image]